# Validating JWT token obtained from Microsoft Graph API in HTTP-triggered functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-function-app

I was able to obtain a JWT token successfully using MSAL pattern from Graph API per the following code snippet below in C#:

```
app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_authenticationSettings.ClientId)
                    .WithClientSecret(_authenticationSettings.ClientSecret)
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri(_authenticationSettings.Authority))
                    .Build();
var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
return result.AccessToken;
```

I am also able to include this token in POST or GET requests' headers as a "Bearer" token to submit to an HTTP-triggered function. How can I validate this token in the function side to ensure it's authentic? All examples online are covering asp.net core applications and I could not find anything relevant to functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/azure-functions?tutorial-step=3) you can find a tutorial how to validate Graph API token in Azure Functions.

[JwtSecurityTokenHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler?view=azure-dotnet) class is used for validating JWT.

Comment: This is the error that I am getting which I could not find a solution for that!!

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect, Version=6.7.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @Arash Maybe similar issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/397 
Accroding the thread the workaround can be adding <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput> in .csproj

Comment: Yes, I got this issue fixed and now got the error message below which I have no idea why!

IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'System.Text.StringBuilder'. 
kid: 'System.String'. 
Exceptions caught:
 'System.Text.StringBuilder'.
token: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken'.